# Como retornar dados do usuario que efetuou o login?

Tags: php, android-studio, session

Preciso que alguém me ajude com o seguinte problema. Eu quero realizar um `select` em um banco de dados MySQL, o select sera feito via Web service com PHP retornando um Json para o meu app Android.

O que acontece, o usuário digita login e senha e o app reconhece o usuário  e abre uma segunda tela, nessa segunda tela tem um `listview` e nesse `listview` deveria conter todas as empresas desse usuário, e é neste ponto que esta o problema. Para eu fazer isso eu realizo um `select` em PHP no banco de dados, porem, o `select` me retorna todas as empresas do banco de dados e não só a do usuário que efetuou o login. Eu tentei salvar o código da empresa utilizando SESSION no PHP porem  não deu certo  gostaria que alguém me ajudasse, obrigado.

Segue o código em PHP:

```
<?php

SESSION_START();
echo $_SESSION['Cod_Empresa'];
mysql_connect('localhost','','');
mysql_select_db('bd') or die (mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query( "SELECT UC, Instalacao, Nome_Logo FROM Tab_UC where Cod_Empresa ='".$_SESSION['Cod_Empresa']."'") or die('Could not query');
 for($rows = array(); $row = mysql_fetch_object($result); $rows[] = $row);
 {
    echo json_encode($rows);    
 } 



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, pelo que entendi você deseja buscar as empresas de um usuário logado.

Olhando tua query vi que tem uma tabela **Tab_UC**, deduzo que seja a tabela responsável pelas empresas cadastradas. E em sua cláusula **where** `Cod_Empresa ='".$_SESSION['Cod_Empresa']."'` vocẽ está filtrando pelo código da empresa. Não deveria filtrar por ID do usuário logado?

Ao meu ver, este código retorná apenas uma empresa.

Comment: e como seria filtrar pelo ID...   poderia me retornar um exemplo...   obrigado